# How to restrict return order in XQuery results?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

This is newbie question. I am just start learning XQuery and XPath recently.

Consider this XML

```
<employees>
    <employee empid="1">
        <ename>KING</ename>
        <mgr></mgr>
        <hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
    </employee>
    <employee empid="2">
        <ename>BLAKE</ename>
        <mgr>7839</mgr>
        <hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
        <test>
            <sub1>one</sub1>
            <sub2>two</sub2>
        </test>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

When I execute the following XQuery,

```
let $db := db:open("example", "documents/employee.xml")
for $item in $db/(/employees/employee,/employees/employee/test)
let $empid := $item/@empid
let $ename := $item/ename
let $sub1 := $item/sub1
let $hiredate := $item/hiredate
let $sub2 := $item/sub2
return ($empid,$ename,$sub1,$hiredate,$sub2)
```

I got...

```
empid="1"
<ename>KING</ename>
<hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
<sub1>empid1-one</sub1>
empid="2"
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
<sub1>empid2-one</sub1>
<sub2>empid2-two</sub2>
```

The result that I am hoping to get is...

```
empid="1"
<ename>KING</ename>
<sub1>empid1-one</sub1>
<hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
empid="2"
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>empid2-one</sub1>
<hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
<sub2>empid2-two</sub2>
```

I want the result order to be base on the order of my return clause.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

har07 already gave a good answer, accept this answer, not mine. Just as an addition, attribute nodes cannot be output without a parent element. You could change the attribute variable like this:

```
let $empid := $item/@empid/concat(name(), '=', ., '&#10;')
```

and if you care about newlines more than about whitespace-only lines:

```
let $empid := $item/@empid/concat('&#10;',name(), '=', ., '&#10;')
```

and the output will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
empid=1
<ename>KING</ename>
<hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
empid=2
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
<hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
<sub2>two</sub2>
```

In fact, the output is not XML at all and there is no point in having an XML declaration. Use

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:omit-xml-declaration "yes";
```

to get rid of the declaration. This should work with the newest version of BaseX. Then, the output will be

```
empid=1
<ename>KING</ename>
<hiredate>17-11-1981</hiredate>
empid=2
<ename>BLAKE</ename>
<sub1>one</sub1>
<hiredate>1-5-1981</hiredate>
<sub2>two</sub2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, XQuery doesn't change the order of return values you have specified. What you observed is due to the fact that your code specifically loops through all `employee` elements first before looping through `test` elements, by saying `in $db/(/employees/employee,/employees/employee/test)`.

Assuming that one `employee` can have only one `test` child, you can try this way instead :

```
let $db := db:open("example", "documents/employee.xml")
for $item in $db/employees/employee
let $empid := $item/@empid
let $ename := $item/ename
let $sub1 := $item/test/sub1
let $hiredate := $item/hiredate
let $sub2 := $item/test/sub2
return ($empid,$ename,$sub1,$hiredate,$sub2)
```

Comment: That does not work because attributes nodes do not attach to anything. How about `let $empid := $item/@empid/concat(name(), '=', ., '&#10;')`?